# Baking results in an all black square, googling is not helping

Tags: uv, texture-baking

I'm trying to bake multiple materials into one UV on one object.

- I made a seperate back UV and made sure it was selected
- I made an image to bake to and put it in an image node inside each
  material in my object
- I put a light next to my object
- I unselected direct and indirect lighting while leaving color on
- I made sure there was no metalic value in any of my materials

I have no idea what to do at this point. I've looked up multiple tutorials and read many other questions about this. Nothing helps.

[image]

Here is a [Higher Resolution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hdxH.jpg)

I also tried making a new image to bake to and made it white, because I wasn't sure if bake was outputting all black, or doing literally nothing. It did turn all black.

Here's the blend file:
[image]

I'm specifically trying to bake "Bulkhead-Lights-005" under the "Corridore" collection.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Update: I made another blend fild and extruded a cube, applied multiple materials and made two UVs with differnt configurations. Baking works fine.

I wonder if something got set different in the blend file?

Comment: The textures are missing from you file so I can't bake anything from it. But if you only want to bake the Diffuse color, you could try to temporarily CTRL+SHIFT+Click on the last node before your Base Color input and bake the Emit instead. It would bake faster and help you debug your problem more efficiently.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the textures aren't there. If I zoom out of the output image node you can see them in the first matereal. There are 8 materials in this object and they all have variouse texture maps. https://i.imgur.com/n8bnbX7.png

Comment: Do you need to bake 8k textures? Why does this 6k verts object consume so much memory? I've appended the object to a fresh blend file, lowered the samples to 10, and tried to bake the texture. It takes forever and memory usage goes up to 13GB. The blender.exe used 20GB Not sure what's going on here.

Comment: There's a lot of 8 and 4 k texture maps throughout the scene. There are eight materials with nigh res texture maps on it that I'm trying to bake down to a single material for that object.

Comment: @user145371 I mean the textures are not in your file, I am talking about the actual images, not the nodes. You have the images on your hard drive, they don't follow along with your blend file unless you pack them, you haven't.